# How to push an object to another object in the same array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
[
        {
            "ID": 227886,
            "post_author": "54"
        },
        {
            "ID": 227545,
            "post_author": "18"
        },
        {
            "ID": 229317,
            "post_author": "22"
        },
        {
            "img": "bang.jpg",
            "id": 229317
        },
        {
            "img": "other.png",
            "id": 227886
        },
        {
            "img": "name.jpg",
            "id": 227545
        }
]
```

I want to push all the objects that have the "img" to the objects that their "ID" is equal to the "img" object's "id".

The expected result:

```
[
        {
            "ID": 227886,
            "post_author": "54",
            "img": "other.png",
            "id": 227886
        },
        {
            "ID": 227545,
            "post_author": "18"
            "img": "name.jpg",
            "id": 227545
        },
        {
            "ID": 229317,
            "post_author": "22",
            "img": "bang.jpg",
            "id": 229317
        }  
]
```

How can I push objects inside other objects in the same array which their "id" and "ID" are the same ?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Separate them with `.filter()`, then `.find()` the matching images and combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new array that just has objects with the post author in them, and another one without:

```
const postAuthorList = initialArray.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('post_author'));
const imgList = initialArray.filter(obj => !obj.hasOwnProperty('post_author'));
```

Then you can loop over the `postAuthorList`, and find the matching object from the `imgList` and combine them via `Object.assign()`:

```
postAuthorList.forEach(postAuthor => Object.assign(postAuthor, imgList.find(img => img.id === postAuthor.ID)))
```

`postAuthorList` will now contain the combine lists. The exact code you write can vary but those are the general steps I would take.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `reduce` in order to group by `ID` or `id` and then take `Object.values` to form array out of the object.

```js
const arr = [ { "ID": 227886, "post_author": "54" }, { "ID": 227545, "post_author": "18" }, { "ID": 229317, "post_author": "22" }, { "img": "bang.jpg", "id": 229317 }, { "img": "other.png", "id": 227886 }, { "img": "name.jpg", "id": 227545 }];

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, o)=>{
    if(o.ID){
        a[o.ID] = {...(a[o.ID] || {}),...o};
    } else {
        a[o.id] = {...(a[o.id] || {}),...o};
    };
    return a;
},{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Object.assign` for the **b** array, the `map()` method of the **a** array. Like that:

```
let c = a.map((row, index) => Object.assign({}, row, b[index]));
```

Full snippet:

```js
let a = [
    {
        ID: 227886,
        post_author: "54",
    },
    {
        ID: 227545,
        post_author: "18",
    },
    {
        ID: 229317,
        post_author: "22",
    },
    {
        img: "bang.jpg",
        id: 229317,
    },
    {
        img: "other.png",
        id: 227886,
    },
    {
        img: "name.jpg",
        id: 227545,
    },
];

let b = [
    {
        img: "other.png",
        id: 227886,
    },
    {
        img: "name.jpg",
        id: 227545,
    },
    {
        img: "bang.jpg",
        id: 229317,
    },
];

let c = a.map((row, index) => Object.assign({}, row, b[index]));

console.log(c);
```